# Injectivity of morphism: 2-folded covering space of wedge sum circle projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

I've read (and I see it more or less clearly) that a 2-folded covering space $\tilde{X}$ of $X=S^1 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2$ is a 2-sphere with 2 unit circles tangently attached to antipodal points. If my reasoning is correct, $\pi_1(\tilde{X}) = \langle a, b \rangle$ is generated by two loops, each one around each circle, while $\pi_1(X) = \langle c, d \mid d^2=1 \rangle$ ($c$ loops around the circle, $d$ is the generator of the group of the plane).

Now, the covering map $\pi$ between them induces an **injective** homomorphism between the fundamental groups. But in this case, the two circles map to the same one in $X$, so $a$ and $b$ both map to $c$. Where is the error, in the covering spaces themselves or my calculation of their fundamental groups? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance :)

EDIT: I include a picture showing how I think the covering would work. Points in $S^2$ get mapped to their projection on the plane, and points in both $S^1$ go to the same position in the $S^1$ of the image.

[image]

Comment: *Notation:* Use `\langle a, b \rangle` for better angle-brackets: $\langle a, b \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have switched around $X$ and $\overline{X}$: $\pi_1(X)\cong\langle c,d|d^2=1\rangle$, rather, and $\pi_1(\overline{X})\cong\langle a,b\rangle$.

So the trouble must be that the map $p:\overline{X}\to X$ which is given by the components $S^1=S^1$ and $S^2\twoheadrightarrow\Bbb RP^2$ is not actually a covering map. Consider, say, any neighbourhood of the base point of $S^1$ (which is forced to be shared by both copies of $S^1$). It pulls back under $p$ to two identical but *nondisjoint* copies in $\overline{X}$ and it is completely impossible to have the "disjoint sheets" condition met. So, $p$ is not a covering.

EDIT: I now see you have defined your space $\overline{X}$ differently to how I expected from the notation $S^1\vee S^2\vee S^1$. The map is now a covering but it does *not* send both $a,b$ to $c$. In this image:

[image]

Observe that while $a\mapsto c$ is true, the loop class associated to $b$ - which *must* be about the same base point as $a$ - actually crosses into a loop around $\Bbb RP^2$ after projection by $p$. Note the purple line around $S^2$ which runs $\beta\to\alpha$: this projects to a generator of $\pi_1(\Bbb RP^2)$. So, $b\mapsto dcd$. And the homomorphism induced by $(a,b)\mapsto(c,dcd)$ *is* an injection. So all is well!

Comment: I don't see how... As I understand, the map works the way I drew, and the two presages are disjoint (I have edited the question to include a picture). But anyhow, what would the covering be then? It is a past exam question and it asks for two non-isomorphic 2-sheet coverings

Comment: Preimages* instead of presages

Comment: @Josemi Judging by your picture, you aren't considering the wedge sum of *all three* spaces, $S^1\vee S^2\vee S^1$. Your space is something different (in that notation, it is implied all wedges are joined at the same basepoint)

Comment: Oh, I'll change it. I came across that notation searching for similar questions and didn't put much thought into it.

Comment: @Josemi I've updated my answer to account for the new definition of $\overline{X}$

Comment: OH! I should've taken more care regarding the basepoint, thank you so much! One last question, if the basepoint in your picture is $\alpha$, the element $b$ should actually be a loop, right? So you'd have to run from $\alpha$ to $\beta$, then loop around the circle, and back to $\alpha$. So wouldn't it be $b \mapsto dcd$ then?

Comment: @Josemi Oh sorry, I forgot to close it off. I guess it should run $\alpha\to\beta\to\beta\to\alpha$, so $b\mapsto dcd$ would be correct ($d^{-1}=d$)